# Scanner - Ignore new line at end of file

Tags: java, newline, java.util.scanner

I need some help with quitting when coming to/ignoring the last new line in the file reg.txt. As of right now I get an error when it reaches the last line, containing nothing.

```
public String load() {
        list.removeAllElements();
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("reg.txt"));

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String lastname = scanner.next();
                String firstname = scanner.next();
                String number = scanner.next();
                list.add(new Entry(firstname, lastname, number));
            }
            msg = "The file reg.txt has been opened";
            return msg;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
            msg = ("Can't find reg.txt");
            return msg;
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            msg = ("Can't find reg.txt");
            return msg;
        }
    }
```

Sample reg.txt:

```
Allegrettho     Albert          0111-27543
Brio            Britta          0113-45771
Cresendo        Crister         0111-27440
```

How should I edit the scanner-reading so that it ignores a new line at the end of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of your loop, do

```
Scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

A dry and dirty way would be to check before every scanner.next() if there is a next line.

```
if(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
  lastname = scanner.next();
}
```

Or after String lastname:

```
if(!lastname.isEmpty())
{
   //continue here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a validation for Entry arguments, is if there any line empty you will skip it.

```
if(firstname != null || lastname != null || number != null) {
    list.add(new Entry(firstname, lastname, number));
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the storing is not the problem, it's the scanner reading. So, I still receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is probably to enclose your data collection inside an if statement to check if the scanner.next() is not null:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    if(!scanner.next().equals("")&&!scanner.next()==null){
        String lastname = scanner.next();
        String firstname = scanner.next();
        String number = scanner.next();
        list.add(new Entry(firstname, lastname, number));
    }
}
```

else I'd look at your hasNextLine method for the logic of saying 'yes I have a next line' when that next line is empty ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the last field using `next()`, use `nextLine()` instead. This will advance the scanner past the end-of-line, but not return the end-of-line character in the result.

`scanner.hasNextLine()` will then be `false`, so the loop will not begin again.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String lastname = scanner.next();
    String firstname = scanner.next();
    String number = scanner.nextLine();
    list.add(new Entry(firstname, lastname, number));
}
```